# Need to make an enumeration of type double in c#

Tags: c#, enumeration

How can I create an enum of type double?

Is it possible or do I have to create some kind of collection and hash?

Answer (score 7):

You can't make it an enumeration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y94acxy2.aspx

One of possibilities:

```
public static class MyPseudoEnum
{
    public static readonly double FirstVal = 0.3;
    public static readonly double SecondVal = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: That won't compile. Your suggested fields should be `static` or `const`.

Comment: What is the reason to prefer `static` over `const` ?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends on how much trouble you want to go to.  You *can* convert a double to a long, so if you converted your double values to long integers in a separate program, and output the constant values, you could then use them in your program.

I would strongly discourage this, by the way, but sometimes you gotta do what ya gotta do.

First, write a program to convert your doubles to longs:

```
    Console.WriteLine("private const long x1 = 0x{0:X16}L;", 
        BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(0.5));
    Console.WriteLine("private const long x2 = 0x{0:X16}L;", 
        BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(3.14));
```

Now, add that output to your program and create the enum:

```
    private const long x1 = 0x3FE0000000000000L;
    private const long x2 = 0x40091EB851EB851FL;

    enum MyEnum : long
    {
        val1 = x1,
        val2 = x2
    }
```

When you want to test a double value against the enum, you'll have to call `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits()`, and cast the result to your enum type.  To convert the other way, call `BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble()`.

Answer (score 2):

No, enums are essentially integer values.

I don't know about your particular problem you're solving but you could do a generic dictionary.

Of course, comparison of doubles is always fun, particularly when they differ way down in the decimals places.  Might be interesting if you try to compare the results of a calculation (for equality) against a known double.  Just a caution, if that is what you might need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Enum types have to be [integral](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w(VS.80).aspx) types, with the exception of `char`.  This doesn't include `double`, so you'll need to make a lookup table or a set of constants.

Comment: char is an integral value (eg. a byte in most ASCII encoding)

Comment: @AZ, What tvanfosson is saying is that although char *is* an integral type it can't be used as the underlying type for an enum.

Answer (score 1):

I think byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong are your only options.

Why, as a matter of interest? Maybe we can work round it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use double for an enum.  See the following MSDN article for an explination of how enums work:

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

Here is a quote from the article that answers your question:

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char. The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use an enum of type double?

If you need sub values, you could just multiply the double values with a constant operator to turn them all into integers (and maintain the same ratio) and then use that same operator to turn your values back to doubles afterwards... If you multiply by the dozens it would just be like temporarily moving the decimal separator to the left. Simple but effective.

Comment: Or you could just create a simple array with the required values next to the enum. Then use to enum's int value to address the right value.