# Vb enum not returning correct value

Tags: vb.net, enums

I'm trying to use an enum and am going mad trying to get the right value out of it.

```
Enum DiscountRates As Long
    x = 0.05
    y = 0.1
    z = 0.15
End Enum
```

So if I do

```
MessageBox.Show(DiscountRates.x)
```

I'd think I would get back .05 or i'd be able to use it to assign a value.... If I print it out it will only ever print 0

I originally had it as a double, but VB won't let it be declared as one

Comment: Interesting that actually compiles and runs because `0.05` is most certainly not a `Long`. It must be implicitly rounding/truncating?

Comment: Maybe Option Strict is set to off?

Answer (score 3):

Enums only support integers. You need to resort to other options, as:

```
   Const x As Single = 0.05
```

Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/655055/290343

Comment: It was originally declared as a double, but it says enums must be declared as integral type

Comment: Sorry, you are right. You can't do it with an `Enum`. Use consts instead. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/655055/290343.
I've edited my answer.

Comment: Or if it's always going to be a percentage value (at even percentage points) you could declare `Enum DiscountRatesPercent` with `x = 5` `y = 10` and `z = 15`.